# Insert Post Array Data into PHP_MYSQLI

Tags: php

This is my HTML code

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls form-inline">
    <input type="text" name="plot_id" class="form-control" disabled="true" value="<?php echo $plot_id; ?>" style="width: 50px;" />
    <input type="text" name="khasra_id" class="form-control" disabled="true" value="<?php echo $khasra_id; ?>" style="width: 50px;"/>
    Plot Number : <input type="text" name="plot[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex 113A/113B/113C"/>
    Area : <input type="text" name="plot[]" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Ex 1000 sq ft "/>
    <input type="text" name="tot" class="form-control" disabled="true" value="<?php echo $tot; ?>" style="width: 50px;"/>
    Facing : <input type="text" name="plot[]" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Ex North/East" />
    Type : <input type="text" name="plot[]" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Ex Ressidental/Comm" />
    Status : <select class="form-control" name="plot[]">
    <option value="Available">Available</option>
    <option value="Book">Book</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
```

This is my php code

```
if(isset($_POST['final_split'])){
                       $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","******","******","********");
                       if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
                         echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                       }
                       foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$insert_into  = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO plot_deatils(plot_id,khasra_id,plot_number,area,tot,facing,typee,statuss) VALUES(
 '$_POST[plot_id]','$_POST[khasra_id]','$_POST[plot][0]','$_POST[plot][0]','$_POST[tot]','$_POST[plot][0]','$_POST[plot][0]','$_POST[plot][0]',   
 )");
                       }
                   }
```

This is my code where i have wrote the db connection.
please some one can help me to solve the above problem which i want to insert the above code to db through the post array data

Comment: You never create a database connection. You are going to need a database, MySQL is a good free option that interacts well with PHP.

Comment: please post all relevant Code. I see no `<form>` tag here, did you forget to put it here, or don't you have it in your page ? As such, it will actually never post anything... and if it does, I see no database connection neither so it wouldn't insert anything.

Comment: Is your database table called `TABLE`?

Comment: The code fragments you posted are incomplete in several ways, as noted above. You should research getting started with MySQL, and then how to interact with your tables using PHP. Also, writing queries that way (with $_POST vars directly in the string) is a HUGE security hole.

Comment: You should create a database connection as @mituw16 said. Check for mysqli_* or PDO functions in the php documentation.

Comment: Yes sir just i was checking whether it is coming into r not.

Comment: If do u have any demo code how to get the post array data and insert into mysqli.

Answer (score 1):

You're just echoing your INSERT statement, if you want it to write in your DB you need to establish a database connection with MySQLi and write your insert as a query, eg:

```
$db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'password', 'database_name');

$stmt = $db->prepare("YOUR INSERT STATEMENT HERE");
$stmt->bind_param( BIND YOUR POST PARAMETERS HERE );
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

This is a pretty technical task and doing it wrong can break things in so many ways so I recommend you thoroughly read the [documentation](https://www.php.net/mysqli) before attempting this.